# Azure Form Recognizer response has all the spaces removed from text

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using the training tool on the fott.azure website to train my model and I was able to label the fields correctly but the tool was removing all the spaces in recognized text. I am having the same issues with the Recognize API too.

Here is an example

*Actual text:* **United States of America**

*JSON Response:* **UnitedStatesofAmerica**

Is there any setting on the training tool to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The FOTT tool will save labeled text in word-level, take the sample text "United States of America" for example, in the label file it will be break into four words:

1. "United", and its bounding box.
2. "States", and its bounding box.
3. "of", and its bounding box.
4. "America", and its bounding box.

When the prediction results are return, predicted fields will also have text in word level. we can join the words with space to assemble back the whole text.

This is by-design behavior for FOTT so unfortunately there isn't configuration for preserving space.

As Neta mentioned, can you please try Form Recognizer 2.1 GA version, in this version I believe there's field "text" property which contains the whole text predicted, this might be what you expected :)

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/GetAnalyzeFormResult

Hope this help, if this post doesn't answer your question, please feel free to contact us using the contact info Neta provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this as spaces shouldn't be removed. Can you please also try the latest Form Recognizer GA version 2.1 on http://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net ?  Would you be able to share the document you tried out ? Please remove any PII before sharing. Feel free to contact us at Form Recognizer Contact Us formrecog_contact@microsoft.com